# Equally distribute and zip two lists of different length in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
B = [1,2,3]
```

A is 3 times longer than B and so I'd like to match them together using that, as below:

```
C = [("a",1"),("b",1"),("c",1),
     ("d",2),("e",2),("f",2),
     ("g",3),("h",3),("i",3)]
```

So the first 3 elements of A are matched with the first element of B, the next 3 elements of A are matched with the second element of B and so on.

Futhermore, this is a very simplistic example. I'd also be interested in how to best fairly distribute the elements when the one list is bigger than the other by a number which is not a whole number. For example, my two lists are 10001 and 511 elements long, so the first is ~19.57 bigger than the second. Preferably I'd like to use every element in both lists.

Comment: What exactly is your question for us? Do you want us to write code for you, give an algorithm, give a hint, or something else? Can you show us an attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume here that first list is the longer.

Here is is simple way:

```
rep = len(A) // len(B)
ia = iter(A)
C = [(next(ia), b) for b in B for i in range(rep)]
C.extend((a, B[-1]) for a in ia)         # in case len(A) is not an exact multiple of len(B)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the length of `A` is a multiple of `B`, you can easily do

```
>>> scale = len(A) // len(B)
>>> [(a, B[i // scale]) for i, a in enumerate(A)] 
[('a', 1),
 ('b', 1),
 ('c', 1),
 ('d', 2),
 ('e', 2),
 ('f', 2),
 ('g', 3),
 ('h', 3),
 ('i', 3)]
```

How it works:

1. Determine the value of `k` such that `len(A) == k * len(B)`
2. Iterate over `A`, and use `k` to determine which value of `B` to pick by dividing the current index by it, accordingly

If the lengths are not multiples, then it will throw a

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You can circumvent this by computing `scale` to be

```
scale = len(A) // len(B) * len(B)
```

For example,

```
A = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
B = [1, 2, 3]
```

```
>>> scale = len(A) // len(B) * len(B)
>>> [(a, B[i // scale]) for i, a in enumerate(A)] 
[('a', 1),
 ('b', 1),
 ('c', 1),
 ('d', 1),
 ('e', 1),
 ('f', 1),
 ('g', 2),
 ('h', 2)]
```

---

Here's a functional approach using `itertools` `repeat` and `chain.from_iterable`.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> list(zip(A, chain.from_iterable(zip(*repeat(B, scale)))))
[('a', 1),
 ('b', 1),
 ('c', 1),
 ('d', 2),
 ('e', 2),
 ('f', 2),
 ('g', 3),
 ('h', 3),
 ('i', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grouper` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` docs (or import it from [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/)).

Recipe:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Application:

```
>>> from more_itertools import grouper                                                               
>>> A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]                                                                          
>>> B = [1,2,3]                                                                                                        
>>> [(x, i) for vals, i in zip(grouper(A, len(B)), B) for x in vals]                                                   
[('a', 1),
 ('b', 1),
 ('c', 1),
 ('d', 2),
 ('e', 2),
 ('f', 2),
 ('g', 3),
 ('h', 3),
 ('i', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and repeat `B` with your own list comprehension:

```
>>> A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
>>> B = [1,2,3]
>>> list(zip(A, (y for x in B for y in len(B) * [x])))
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 2), ('e', 2), ('f', 2), ('g', 3), ('h', 3), ('i', 3)]
```

It's also recommended not to hardcode `len(B) * 3`, and use `scale = len(A) // len(B)` to get the proportional distribution, as shown in [@coldspeed's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872517/equally-distribute-and-zip-two-lists-of-different-length-in-python/53872544#53872544) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also group `A` into a list of sublists, each sublist the length of `B`:

```
A = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"]
B = [1,2,3]
_b = len(B)
new_a = [A[i:i+_b] for i in range(0, len(A), _b)]
final_result = [(c, i) for a, i in zip(new_a, B) for c in a]
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 2), ('e', 2), ('f', 2), ('g', 3), ('h', 3), ('i', 3)]
```